# Data and HTML Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

So I'm trying to populate a HTML dropdown using Javascript/Jquery.  I'd like each `<option>` tag to have some data associated with it, stuff like searchPurpose, searchTime, startDate, endDate.  I then have two questions-

1. How should I associate that data - through data tags, or through something else?
2. How do I access that data once my user has clicked on a certain option?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using JQuery, or is this strictly Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HTML5, `data-*` attributes are definitely the way to go. Suppose you have the following:

```
<select id="ddl">
  <option data-start-date="25-08-2012" value="1">A</option>
  <option data-start-date="25-08-2013" value="1">B</option>
</select>
```

To access their value with plain JavaScript use:

```
selectedOption.getAttribute("data-start-date");
```

With jQuery use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
$("#ddl").on('change', function () {
  var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  alert($(selectedOption).data("start-date"));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RVVpN/)**.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6zZB/)** (jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery? If so, you may want to use the built-in data module. 
If not, use data tags. I suggest putting all the data in one data tag. 
i.e.

```
data="searchPurpose: thing, searchTime: sometime"
```

and separating it like this:

```
function data(elem) {
    var data = {};
    var a = elem.getAttribute('data').split(',');
    var i = 0;
    while(i < a.length){
        data[a[i].split(':')[0]] = a[i].split(':')[1];
        i++;
    }
    return data;
}
```

So:

```
data() returns an object literal like this: { searchPurpose: 'thing', searchTime: 'sometime' }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to associate data with the `option` tags. Some ideas off of the top of my head:

- Use hidden inputs: `<option id="option1">Option 1</option><input type="hidden" id="option1data" value="option1 data here" />`
- Use `data-` attributes (not supported by all browsers): `<option id="option1" data-searchPurpose="searchPurpose">Option 1</option>`
- If you're using jQuery, you can use [its .data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/): `$('#option1').data('searchPurpose', 'data...');`

As far as accessing the data, it depends on what you're doing with your dropdowns. If they're being submitted in a form, you could use some `onSubmit` JavaScript to **a)** return false *and then* **b)** submit the form using `post` or `get` with the extra data appended.
(In the case of the hidden input solution, this JavaScript intervention would not be necessary.)

Otherwise it should be very simple using Javascript to access/modify the data.